# Wordpress 3.8.1 Multisite Subdirectory WP-Admin 404 Error - Tried Everything

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Domain is www.sandersonathletics.org

Wordpress 3.8.1, Multisite with Subdirectory.

The error thats cropping up is identified on the new subdirectory site; 
www.sandersonathletics.org/football - **Unformatted** AND
www.sandersonathletics.org/football/wp-admin **404 Error**

1. I've verified the .htaccess file matches what's in Wordpress.
2. I've verified the appropriate location of .htaccess (public_html root)
3. I've verified the wp-config file and that the location of the multisite data is in the right place and I've checked what's there.
4. I've reviewed entries in the mysql database and that the www. matches in wp-config, the database, etc. (The host suggested this)
5. I've renamed the plug-in directory to plugin-bak to debug a plugin issue. That had no effect.
6. I'm currently hosted with Dreamhost Shared servers.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Updated actions I've taken to try and get this working. Day 3, still can not get this to work;  7. I've attempted changing mod_rewrite.c to .so based on past advice. 
That didn't work, so I changed it back.
8. I've set all permissions on contents, includes, and admin to 755 
permissions recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 WP 4.9.7 and PHP7:

> Source:
>   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167294/multisite-404-error-for-subdirectory

Edit this file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/.conf

to make it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The part that makes it works is:

```
<Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Restart apache:

> sudo service apache2 restart

There you have it! test your sites.